# How do I pass boost signal to a function to be used somewhere else?

Tags: c++, boost, signals-slots

This is defined as a public member of a class.

```
boost::signals2::signal<void (int, std::string, std::string, int)> sigApp;
```

Want to pass the signal like this:-

```
Application* newApp = new Application(pSn, &mdCache_, &sigApp);
```

Using it:-

```
(*sigApp)(Msg.getAsInt( var ), var2, var3, var4); //Signal Used
```

The program quits here during runtime.
How should I pass boost signal to a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to pass a `signal`, you are expected to "connect" some callback(s) to invoke when the signal is *raised*. For instance:

```
boost::signals2::signal< void(int, std::string, std::string, int) > sigApp;

sigApp.connect([](int a, std::string b, std::string c, int d)
{
    // do something
});

sigApp.connect([](int a, std::string b, std::string c, int d)
{
    // do another thing
});

// raise the event
sigApp(1, "b", "c", 2);
```

You're all set.

Comment: It is bind to a method, just that the signal is raised in a different class/method than where it is defined.

Comment: @DarkKnight then pass the object that holds the signal and expose a reference to that signal so you can connect callbacks elsewhere. It is probably not a good idea to pass your naked signal so everybody can raise it.